# formato de fechas r

Tags: r, date, formato, date-format

Tengo un df con dos columnas de tipo "character" con el año y el mes, tengo que hacer una fecha con estas dos. He hecho la columna de esta forma, quedandome un string:

```
df$date <- paste(df$year, df$month, sep = "-")



$ date           <chr> "2008-may", "2008-may", "2008-may", "2008-may", "2008-may"…
```

El problema viene cuando intento darle formato "Date" ya que si uso as.Date, no hay formato válido. He probado "%Y-%b" y no hay manera, he cambiado el idioma del locale pero tampoco lo consigo, alguna solucion? muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en las funciones bases no tienes un objeto fecha que sea solo año/mes. Lo que puedes hacer es completar el día y recién ahí aplicar `as.date()`:

```
am <- c("2008-may", "2008-ene", "2008-dic", "2008-oct")
as_date(paste0(am, '-01'), format="%Y-%b-%d")

[1] "2008-05-01" "2008-01-01" "2008-12-01" "2008-10-01"
```